# Best way to get the overlapping segment of two lines

Tags: oracle-spatial

Could anyone help me figure out the best way to get the overlapping line segment of 2 line sdo_geometry objects?

my query looks like this:

```
select SDO_GEOM.SDO_INTERSECTION(SHAPE, :SHAPE, 0.5) as geom
from MyTable 
where MDSYS.SDO_OVERLAPS(SHAPE, :SHAPE) = 'TRUE'
```

the geometry objects in the table are all lines as is eth parameter being passed in, but the geometry being returned for all results is a point, not a line.

Comment: Just a wild guess, is that there may be some option to specify the output geometry type.  In many packages the default output is a line, so check O-S to see if you can modify the output.  I know it can be done in other packages, but for specific input geometries.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the lines are overlapping, not just crossing each other?

```
create table test (TestID number, shape SDO_GEOMETRY);
Insert into test values (1, SDO_GEOMETRY(2002, NULL, null, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,2,1),  SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY (1,1, 4,4)));
Insert into test values (2, SDO_GEOMETRY(2002, NULL, null, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,2,1),  SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY (1,4, 4,1)));
insert into user_sdo_geom_metadata values ('test', 'SHAPE', SDO_DIM_ARRAY(SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Lat', -180, 180, 0.05), SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Long', -90, 90, 0.05)), NULL);
create index test_indx on test(shape) indextype is mdsys.spatial_index;
select SDO_GEOM.SDO_INTERSECTION(SHAPE, SDO_GEOMETRY(2002, NULL, null, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,2,1),  SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY (2,2, 5,5)), 0.5) as geom
from test 
where MDSYS.SDO_OVERLAPS(SHAPE, SDO_GEOMETRY(2002, NULL, null, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,2,1),  SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY (2,2, 5,5))) = 'TRUE';
```

Results in

```
SDO_GEOMETRY(2002, NULL, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 2, 1), SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(2, 2, 4, 4))
SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, NULL, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1, 1), SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(2, 2))
```

In the second case, a line can't be returned because the lines only intersect at a point.  Playing around with this, the only ways I could filter the result set was based on gtype or testing to see in the intersection of the A and B shapes is covered by the A shape.

```
select SDO_GEOM.SDO_INTERSECTION(SHAPE, SDO_GEOMETRY(2002, NULL, null, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,2,1),  SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY (2,2, 5,5)), 0.5) as geom
from test
where MDSYS.SDO_OVERLAPBDYDISJOINT(SHAPE, SDO_GEOMETRY(2002, NULL, null, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,2,1),  SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY (2,2, 5,5))) = 'TRUE'
and SDO_GEOM.SDO_INTERSECTION(SHAPE, SDO_GEOMETRY(2002, NULL, null, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,2,1),  SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY (2,2, 5,5)), 0.5).SDO_GTYPE = 2002;

SDO_GEOMETRY(2002, NULL, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 2, 1), SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(2, 2, 4, 4))
```

or:

```
select SDO_GEOM.SDO_INTERSECTION(SHAPE, SDO_GEOMETRY(2002, NULL, null, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,2,1),  SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY (2,2, 5,5)), 0.5) as geom
from test
where MDSYS.SDO_OVERLAPBDYDISJOINT(SHAPE, SDO_GEOMETRY(2002, NULL, null, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,2,1),  SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY (2,2, 5,5))) = 'TRUE'
and MDSYS.SDO_COVERS (SHAPE, SDO_GEOM.SDO_INTERSECTION(SHAPE,SDO_GEOMETRY(2002, NULL, null, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,2,1),  SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY (2,2, 5,5)), 0.5)) = 'TRUE';

SDO_GEOMETRY(2002, NULL, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 2, 1), SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(2, 2, 4, 4))
```

These may not be the best solutions, but hopefully it gets you in the right direction.